# Can't link Google Console with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm trying to link my google console with google analytics after I have verified my website as a domain. But according to GA there are no sites verified and there is a site but this is not linked to any web property in google analytics account. [image]See attachment.  Now I have read that I should verify the property as a prefix instead. I'm not sure whether this is the solution. The problem is that I don't how to test it since the property is already been verified as a domain I don't know how to verify it again as a URL prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the domain verification in place.
Create another new url prefix property in google search console, based on the canonical domain, then verify it as well.

For verifying a url prefix property you can use html file upload method, html meta tag method, the google analytics tracking code, or google tag manager container code. 
Further instructions on how to verify ownership via any of these methods are available on the following page:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en